# How to isolate the most disk-active process(es) in OS X?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, performance, command-line

I have some process(es) performing a lot of drive access from time to time, however I've hitherto been unable to isolate which process or processes are performing the access.  What shell command can I issue to isolate the most disk access intensive processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After fiddling with making my own solution via `fs_usage` manipulation, I discovered the DTrace `iotop` script (`man iotop`).  This really seems to do the trick with regards to giving samples of filesystem activity at nice updated intervals and quickly allows one to isolate possibly misbehaving processes.

***NOTE**: you must run it with `sudo` or as `root` user.

For example:

```
sudo iotop -C 5   # Simply gives an update every 5 seconds in default output format without clearing screen.
sudo iotop -CP 2  # Gives 2 second interval updates w/o clearing screen and I/O time based output.
```

Options:

```
iotop [-C] [-D|-o|-P] [-j|-Z] [-d device] [-f filename] [-m mount_point] [-t top] [interval [count]]

   -C     don't clear the screen
   -D     print delta times - elapsed, us
   -j     print project ID
   -o     print disk delta times, us
   -P     print %I/O (disk delta times)
   -Z     print zone ID
   -d device
          instance name to snoop (eg, dad0)
   -f filename
          full pathname of file to snoop
   -m mount_point
          mountpoint for filesystem to snoop
   -t top print top number only
```

Comment: The other very useful commands to focus in on what is happening are DTrace based rwsnoop and iosnoop

Comment: Yes @TheTentacle, I've used `iosnoop` a lot, but generally found `fs_usage` to be faster.  Will have to play with `rwsnoop`, thanks.